# How to destructure the return value of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a better syntax for writing the following code, and I would like to know if there is an option for assigning the return value of a function by using a destructuring assignment:

```js
const object = {
  property: 10,
  getFunction() {
    return "getFunction value";
  }
}

const {property, getFunction} = object;

console.log("Property: ", property, " getFunction: ", getFunction);
```

Here, this code returns the following, which is totally normal:

```
"Property: 10, getFunction: [Function: getFunction]"
```

I'd like to know if there is a syntax option to write something like: (won't work)

```
const {property, getFunctionValue: getFunction()} = object;
```

And get the `"getFunction value"` from the assignment.

Comment: I could wrong, but I don't think that is possible

Comment: Maybe you can use the Object.entries() method to get an array of key-value pairs for the object, then use the Array.prototype.forEach() method to iterate over the array and assign the values to variables with matching names?

Comment: Because I'm looking to get the return value of the function, this is the point of the question actually

Comment: I'm open to feedback if you think I can improve the question.

Comment: You could call the function like so : `getFunction: (() => {
    return "getFunction value";
  })()`, so the object has the value in it and not the function, so when you destructure you get the value. Not sure if it's what you want though

Comment: Yeah the thing is I can't change the API, just wanted to use the API function and get the value as this was a property using object method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortuntely, the syntax you're looking for doesn't exist (I've also wanted to do it many, many times). You can't *call* a function you're retrieving as part of a destructuring operation.¹ You're not allowed to use an arbitrary expression for the "from" part of a destructuring pattern. Destructuring always does property access, not function calls.

You'll have to do it separately, e.g.:

```
const { property } = object;
const getFunctionValue = object.getFunction();
```

or similar.

---

¹ unless it's the getter function for an accessor property

Comment: Fine then, just wanted to double check. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann - I've wanted to do this So Many Times... :-)